# Conditional formatting a whole column based on the value of another column

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting to all of my column D. If Column D is < or > then the value in F by 150 (in the same row), I want it to highlight red. If the value of D is within the 150 above of below of the value in F then I want it to highlight green.

For example: D2 (360) is more than 150 more than F2 (88), so I want it to highlight red. 
D10 (200) if within the 150 more or less range than F10 (275) so I want it to highlight green.

Below is the picture for the fields

***Fields and Data***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Format your cells all green. Then apply CF to cells where the difference is greater than 150 to colour those cells red. Here is the formula to use.

```
=ABS(D2-F2)>150
```